# How to make sure Uri.parse() always returns valid values in java/android?

Tags: java, android, http, url, uri

In java (well in android but i think this its a general problem),

I do this

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("www.google.ca"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

But then it crashes. I then tried this:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.ca"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

And that worked. It seems adding the `http://` makes it work.

The link is something a client will type in, so theres no guarantee that what they type will be valid. Is there a way to fix the link so it makes sure it will work on the Uri.parse(), so it works for all cases? And if its not valid, then I should be able to detect it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check for "http://" or "https://" in the string, if found pass it for URI or append in the beginning.

**Checking:**

```
str1.toLowerCase().contains(str2.toLowerCase())
```

**Appending:**

```
str3 = "htttp://"+str2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can't make sure what input you get. So I think you can check it with regex pattern.
I think this pattern works.

```
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("^(http|https)://[a-z|A-z]{1,}.[a-z|A-Z]{1,}.[a-z|A-Z]{2,}$");
```

This will lead to a url that can be parsed for sure.
But for most people,they tend to input something like www.xxx.com,so I suggest using the following pattern to check again if previous pattern not matched

```
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("^[a-z|A-z]{1,}.[a-z|A-Z]{1,}.[a-z|A-Z]{2,}$");
```

and add http:// at the beggining of the url